# Zip files/Directories in Groovy with AntBuilder

Tags: ant, groovy, antbuilder

I am trying to zip files and directories in Groovy using AntBuilder. I have the following code:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.zip(basedir: "./Testing", destfile:"${file}.zip",includes:file.name)
```

This zips the file "blah.txt", but not the file "New Text Document.txt". I think the issue is the spaces. I've tried the following:

```
ant.zip(basedir: "./Testing", destfile:"${file}.zip",includes:"${file.name}")
ant.zip(basedir: "./Testing", destfile:"${file}.zip",includes:"\"${file.name}\"")
```

Neither of the above resolved the issue. I'm using Ant because it will zip directories, and I don't have access to org.apache.commons.io.compression at work.

Comment: give us the idea about your environment (OS, Groovy version etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [docs for the ant zip task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html), the includes parameter is described as:

> comma- or space-separated list of patterns of files that must be included

So you're right, that it is the space separator that's breaking it...

You need to use the longer route to get this to work:

```
new AntBuilder().zip( destFile: "${file}.zip" ) {
  fileset( dir: './Testing' ) {
    include( name:file.name )
  }
}
```